# Verify that Winform drawing has been done correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

The reason I ask about this:

I'm studying programming in college and I have two mates here, who are blind. We have a class called basic computer graphics, and we use GDI+ (C# winform, System.Drawing classes).

As far as I know, there is no notification method built in .NET to let the user know if the drawing has been done correctly. Are there any alternative ways, or do you have any ideas of what should I look for to solve this problem? This is a serious thing, these guys can write any code, but they need somebody near to check the results every time they're debugging.

I'm willing the code the whole thing, only I don't know where would be the best point to start. Thanks!

Comment: First you have to define the metrics.  What does "drawn correctly" mean?  Once you've enumerated the points you need to check, check them.  There's no canned notification.

Comment: I need to be notified if the drawing has happened, it is beyond bounds (though that is easy to solve); to check if it is in the place where it should be (for example, I'm not sure if my calculation will place the endpoint of my line drawing to the right place (maybe because I'm trying to calculate angles), but I can draw a circle or a rectangle, so I compare their position or check if they meet. etc).

Comment: How do you think enumerating the points? The point objects, or the drawn pixels? I'd really like to see something which would be able to do the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the error code from most GDI+ operations, but this just gives you errors (or OK).

There are two other types of failures I can think of:

1 - If you draw something outside the target, or with the background color, you may fail but not generate an error.

2 - You can draw the wrong thing or wrong color or in the wrong location.

Here's one way to approach the problem:

1 - For each drawing operation, provide a bitmap of what it should look like at that point.

2 - After each drawing operation, they should call a function to compare their bitmap with the provided "correct" bitmap.

This will only work if the bitmaps are identical -- so the problem specs (or at least the implementation) would have to take that into account. It will also not work for cursor animation, etc. But it may be a big time saver if it can be done.

Comment: In my opinion bitmap is a bad choice.  I have to relay somehow on the objects, because drawn and colored pixels can't be calculated with, as far as I know.